# VBA use Strings and Integers to search with

Tags: vba, excel

Alright so I am looking for a way to use a string in a Cells.Find code. the code will search for text that I put in instead of Job & "~" & up but I need it to look for this. Thanks

```
Dim Job As String
Dim Up As Integer

Job = Range("C3").Value

For x = 0 To 10
Up = x + 1

'This is where I am having problems with searching for the String and Integer.

Cells.Find(What:= Job & "~" & up, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Next x
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding extra tilde:

```
Cells.Find(What:= Job & "~~" & Up, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Excel [uses tilde `~` as escape character](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214138/en-us).

Comment: Because excel use tilde as escape character, further info in:
[link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214138/en-us)

Comment: There you go. Now the answer is better. +1